# Webpage background changes on holidays

Tags: html, css, background

I've made a few different backgrounds for my website (in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z5e3b5c8p1xlfum/AABZ2YzPdcuBB7zp5gqR2-O9a?dl=0)), and I would like for them to automatically change on certain, Ex) Christmas, Halloween, etc. I *could* change them manually, but there's no fun in that.  :)
If anyone has any help, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: this will require JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this script and change date according your need

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var ToDay=new Date();
    var Month=ToDay.getMonth();
    var Date=ToDay.getDate();
    var Image=false;

    if (ToDay.getFullYear()==2015){
     if (Month==0){  // January
      if (Date>=20&&Date<=30){
       Image='One.gif';
      }
     }
     if (Month==1){  // Febuary
      if (Date>=20&&Date<=25){
       Image='Three.gif';
      }
     }

    }

    if (Image){
     document.body.style.backgroundImage='url(imagefoldername/'+Image+')';
    }

    /*]]>*/
    </script>
```